# Laravel SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451

Tags: php, laravel

There are some problems with delete function on one table. I need a function that will handle the exception for foreign key constraints. 
Have to fix that function so I can add softdelete.
I tried to copy one column from that same table and when I deleted everything is good, but there are 2 columns that I can't delete.
I will put delete function here.
If you need some more code from software please inform me, but I think this is all you need to know what is the problem.

> **Error massage**: pastebin.com/CktBbbaX (Can't post on the stack for some reason)

This is php function:

```
 public function destroy($id)
        {
            Rate::findOrFail($id)->delete();

            return redirect()->back()->with('status', __('messages/success.delete'));
        }
```

Rates table, as you can see i already have CASCADE function for deleting but still don't work.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('house_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->boolean('b4g_edit');
            $table->integer('derived_qty')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('derived_price')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('limit_quantity')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('round_prices', 10, 3);

            // TRANSLATABLE
            $table->integer('name_frontend')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('name_backend')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('description')->unsigned();
            // END TRANSLATABLE

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers')->onDelete('SET NULL');
            $table->foreign('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses')->onDelete('SET NULL');
            //translation foreign keys
            $table->foreign('name_frontend')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('name_backend')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('description')->references('group_id')->on('translations')->onDelete('CASCADE');         
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rates');
    }
```

And this is rate-parts:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rate_parts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('rate_id')->unsigned();
            $table->enum(
                'product_type',
                [ 'overnight','transport','activity','addon' ]
            );
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->date('date_from');
            $table->date('date_to');
            $table->enum(
                'type',
                [
                    'dummy',
                    'quantity',
                    'price',
                    'closed',
                    'cta',
                    'ctd',
                    'minstay',
                    'start',
                    'expire',
                    'min',
                    'max',
                    'max_beds',
                    'persons',
                    'daily_price',
                    'km_price',
                    'pricechange_abs',
                    'pricechange_rel'
                ]
            );
            $table->decimal('value', 10, 2);

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->index(['product_id', 'product_type']);
            $table->foreign('rate_id')->references('id')->on('rates');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rate_parts');
    }
```

And this is last table translations. (Again problems with implementing code on stack)

> pastebin.com/h15Qe5mR

Comment: Someone? It's really urgent :)

Comment: Yes, first it must create rates and than rate_parts, so rates table exists.

Comment: ohh sorry I'm totally missunderstand you. I thought error occuring while migrating migrations.. Well you can't delete rows because you didin't say what happened when you deleted that record. Because you have rate.id and rate_parts table using that id. You can't just delete it. You need to say what will happen to that relation. for example let say `$table->foreign('rate_id')->references('id')->on('rates')->onDelete("cascade");` so when we delete rate record, related records wil be deleted

Comment: Already tried that method in rate table. It's still the same.
Yup tried again and it's same error.

Comment: can you just your rate_parts table too ?

Comment: You mean to put that same code on rate_parts?

Comment: I mean set `-onDelete("cascade")` on rate_parts migration. Because it relation with ids of rates table

Comment: Already tried this, still nothing.
$table->foreign('rate_id')->references('id')->on('rates')->onDelete('CASCADE');

Comment: Hmm now something interesting happened. I deleted rate_parts manually, and now there is error with another table trip_services.

Comment: it's really getting awkward..

Comment: Yes, so i give that issue to lead developer to fix it. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: sorry, I couldn't help :/

Comment: No problem.  You have big respect form me anyway! :)